# bq decorator behavior against disk and streaming buffer

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to utilize [bigquery's decorator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators) but there is some behaviors I want to confirm.

After some experiment, we found that query result of same absolute interval is not the same by different time of executing the query. If I query a live-streaming table of a very recent hour interval by say batch-issuing 60 queries, each of granularity of one minute, I can see very even distribution of data output for every query. However if I query the same hour interval after say 2 hours. The output loads become very skewed. I see many minutes with output size 0 and suddenly a spike in one minute interval contains almost all the data of that hour.

For example, for querying the same table with absolute value from timestamp 8:00AM to 9:00AM

If I execute the query at say 9:10AM, I get number of rows output with distribution like:

```
8:01AM - 8:02AM: 12
8:02AM - 8:03AM: 9
8:03AM - 8:04AM: 10
8:04AM - 8:05AM: 22
8:05AM - 8:06AM: 15
…
```

If I execute the query at say 11:00AM, I get result number of output rows like:

```
8:01AM - 8:02AM: 0
8:02AM - 8:03AM: 0
8:03AM - 8:04AM: 0
8:04AM - 8:05AM: 0
8:05AM - 8:06AM: 0 
…
8:20AM - 8:21AM: 123
…
```

I assume that difference is caused by whether the data is in streaming buffer or disk. However it is kind of undermining the idempotency of query a given range of same table and causes a lot of complexity of using it. Therefore I want to have some expected behaviors clarified.

1. Is the difference in this query result really caused by the data residence between streaming buffer and disk?
2. Assuming the difference is because of (1), when a data is flushed from buffer to disk, will that data be reallocated to a screenshot of future timestamp or might it be possible to reallocated to an past timestamp. The question relates to whether it is possible to miss any streaming data when using the decorator.
3. When exposed to query result, is it guaranteed that reallocation of data is atomic? Namely for same row, it will only be versioned with one server timestamp?
4. Assuming the scenario when data is re-allocated to a screenshot of future timestamp. Is possible for BQ to provide transactional read on query groups anyhow. Say if I am batching multiple queries of a table, each query covers a unique minute interval while at the same time these queries get executed there is buffer flushing at the background. Is possible that the same data will appear in more than one query output. The question relates to whether it is possible to get duplicate data when using the decorator.

EDIT:

Some additional observation. I found out that after some time, the query result will be stabilized, namely the result of the same query will not change over the time I execute them. I assume it is because of the data "snapshot" of that time range have gotten finalized. So is it possible for me to know how open does BigQuery flush their data from buffer and how often do data get snapshotted? (or whatever mechanism that determine the query result of bq decorator). Namely is there a guaranteed time cutup on when the output of bq decorator can be finalized?

Comment: my query is something like `SELECT * FROM [my_bq_table@1490217780000-1490217840000]`. so i assume the there is some logic underneath that each data is associated with a timestamp such that to determine whether it is belonged to the query interval.

Comment: ohh i simply used python library `time.mktime(datetime(year, month, date, hour, 0).timetuple()` and i am experimenting on a single machine. so it is the utc timestamp of my local clock at each minutes.